# Revenuecat React-Native offerings gets empty object?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I'm using **revenuecat** for in-app purchase I want to add "Monthly subscription", So I follow the [Docs](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/entitlements) for configuration.
and set up everything as they wrote.

For code part

In App.js

```
import Purchases from 'react-native-purchases';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
...
    Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
    Purchases.setup('apiKey');
  }

......
}
```

here a specific screen here should I return the price, name, time "monthly" and other data ([display product](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/displaying-products))

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Purchases from 'react-native-purchases';

export default class OneMonthPurchases extends Component {
  getOfferings = async () => {
    try {
      const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
      console.log('offerings', offerings); // offerings: {"all": {}}
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error when get offerings', error);
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getOfferings();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>One Month Purchases</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but when I log offers I got `offerings: {"all": {}}`
So how can I solve it Or I miss something?

*Note: I test on simulator*

Answer (score 3):

RevenueCat has a guide on the most common reasons for this error in their Help Center here: https://support.revenuecat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041793174-Why-are-my-products-offerings-or-available-packages-empty-

The below answer is pulled from that article:

If you're still testing in sandbox, it's most likely a configuration issue that's preventing the products from being retrieved from Apple/Google. Your product identifiers are set in RevenueCat, but the actual products that your users purchase can only be retrieved directly from Apple/Google. Because this communication happens between your app and the stores, RevenueCat doesn't have any visibility into the API requests, however there are some common issues we see.

- The product identifier set in RevenueCat matches exactly with the store
  You're testing on a physical device and not a simulator
- The bundle Id [iOS] or package name [Android] are set correctly in your app
  Products are in the in the 'Ready To Submit' state [iOS]
- You've signed your 'Paid Applications Agreement' [iOS]
- Your app is published on a closed track and you've added a tester [Android]

If your app is live and everything was working during testing, you should check that:

- All products are in the 'Approved' state in App Store Connect [iOS]
- Products have been approved for 24hrs+. Due to app store propagation time, it can take 24hrs+ for new products to become available after being approved - this is the same for new apps and adding new products to existing apps.

Comment: I don't get this point ( The product identifier set in RevenueCat matches exactly with the store You're testing on a physical device and not a simulator ) this mean should be the same or not? For example ( in apple store, the identifier "com.myApp.1month" so that's should be same in RevenueCat?) And another question no other way to test anything in simulator?

Comment: For the product identifiers, whatever you have set in Apple/Google need to be set exactly on the Offering in RevenueCat. RevenueCat will use this identifier to try and fetch the product from Apple/Google on the device. For iOS, a lot of the simulators are flakey and don't work with any StoreKit APIs - Android simulators are much more stable with IAP.

Comment: Well, we are just targeting iOS right now.     if I just try physical Android is the code base difference between ios & Android? Because I want to deploy it for iOS without change anything if it works in Android! Or should change something else?

Comment: It could be an App Store Connect configuration issue as well that would persist into production, e.g. the Paid Applications Agreement is missing, your products are missing metadata, or the product identifiers are incorrect in RevenueCat.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, after change the product identifiers to same as in the app store, it works and I can display the product,
But I've faced another issue when I make a purchase I got this error `handling Error: There was a problem with the App Store` I've seen this [thread](https://docs.revenuecat.com/discuss/5d6cd49434b48f001c51efd4) but I couldn't know the major issue in this case!